# rewritecond exclude url in .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have these working rewrite rules :

```
# Allow access to assets folder from plugins folders
RewriteRule ^app/plugins/(.+)/assets - [L]

# forbid access to files and folders under app
RewriteRule ^app/.*$ - [L,F]

# rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I would like to exclude from these rules everything located under http://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/...
Therefore I've added a new rewrite condition :

```
...
# rewrite to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/wordpress\/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it dosen't work. When I try to access something like this  : 
http://www.mywebsite.com/wordpress/contact-us/

it redirects me to index.php...

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found what was going wrong with all of this : 
In fact I did not notice that a .htaccess file was present in my /wordpress directory.
So on the .htaccess of my root directory I've added this rule on top of all the others :

```
RewriteRule ^wordpress - [L]
```

Then in the .htaccess of the wordpress directory I've these rules :

```
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

I don't know if everything is optimized but it works !